# how to bring each alternative row to next column

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(X1 = structure(c(6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c(">sp1", 
"CQLSKG", "KLALQLHP", "MVEAI", "SV=1", "SV=2"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I want to have an output like this. So the first row stays then second row comes in front of the first row in next column. then alternatively each row comes in front

```
       X1  X2
1     SV=2 MVEAI   
2     SV=1 KLALQLHP
3     >sp1 CQLSKG
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work

```
data.frame(X1 = unlist(df)[c(TRUE,FALSE)], X2 = unlist(df)[!c(TRUE,FALSE)])

      X1       X2
X11 SV=2    MVEAI
X13 SV=1 KLALQLHP
X15 >sp1   CQLSKG
```

Comment: Or `data.frame(X1 = df[c(TRUE, FALSE),], X2 = df[!c(TRUE, FALSE),])` with no need to `unlist`

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(df), 2)))

    X1       X2
1 SV=2    MVEAI
2 SV=1 KLALQLHP
3 >sp1   CQLSKG
```